# having trouble making popover view the correct size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am displaying a popover when user clicks into text field. The popover view has a picker view but I am having some trouble getting rid of some white space in the view popover . 
This is what it looks like:

[image]

I think my popover size might be fixed because I display it like this when user begins editing textfield:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:textField.frame inView:self.view   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Any ideas on how to make the popover view smaller or for everything to fit in nicely?
I also played around with this line of code but no success:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(360.0,220.0);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're setting the picker's origin to {0, 0}?

Comment: thanks I didn't think of that. I went to IB builder and moved my picker up to the origin and that fixed my problem.